# Numba try: if array.shape[1] - error: tuple index out of range. works without numba, doesn't work with @njit(fastmath=True, nogil=True, cache=True)

Tags: python, numba, try-except

Numba 0.53.1, Python 3.7.9, Windows 10 64bit

This doctest works fine:

```
import numpy as np

def example_numba_tri(yp):
    """
    >>> example_numba_tri(np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1]))
    array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],
           [0.5, 0.1, 0.4],
           [0.2, 0.7, 0.1]])
    """
    try:
        if yp.shape[1] == 3:
            pass
    except:
        yp = yp.reshape(int(len(yp) / 3), -1, order='F')

    return yp
```

Just add `@njit(fastmath=True, nogil=True, cache=True)`:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit(fastmath=True, nogil=True, cache=True)
def example_numba_tri(yp):
    """
    >>> example_numba_tri(np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1]))
    array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],
           [0.5, 0.1, 0.4],
           [0.2, 0.7, 0.1]])
    """
    try:
        if yp.shape[1] == 3:
            pass
    except:
        yp = yp.reshape(int(len(yp) / 3), -1, order='F')

    return yp
```

and get an error:

```
    numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
    Internal error at <numba.core.typeinfer.StaticGetItemConstraint object at 0x0000020CB55A7608>.
    tuple index out of range
    During: typing of static-get-item at C:/U1/main.py (1675)
    Enable logging at debug level for details.
    
    File "main.py", line 1675:
    def example_numba_tri(yp):
        <source elided>
        try:
            if yp.shape[1] == 3:
            ^
```

How to fix it and why this happen? Or this is a bug?
I read https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#pysupported-exception-handling , but seems I did everything as it written there.

Updates:

1. https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6872
2. Also this was useful for me https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile
3. profiling and restructing helped me convert to numba only most cpu-intensive parts
4. numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html seems
   no support for `order` (`order='F'`)

Comment: It's in doctest format: https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html . Is it ok as a minimal reproducible example?

Or just run `example_numba_tri(np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1]))` from main

Comment: The issue is, that numba „backs in“ the number of dimension in the produced jit-code, there is no dispatch during the runtime. When you pass an one dimensional array, shape[1] doesn’t make sense (only shape[0]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider to rewrite your code another way, since it looks like your Numba code checks types of input data so block `if yp.shape[1] == 3:` is checked in compilation stage, that is why it is not handled by `try except`

Please try the code below, it is identical to your code, but there is no `order='F'` which does not want to work with Numba in any way.

```py
from numba import njit
import numpy as np


@njit(fastmath=True, nogil=True, cache=True)
def example_numba_tri(yp):
    return yp.reshape(int(len(yp) / 3), -1)


def wrapper_example_numba_tri(yp):
    if len(yp.shape) > 1:
        if yp.shape[1] == 3:
            return yp
    return example_numba_tri(yp)


if name == 'main':
    x = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1])
    wrapper_example_numba_tri(x)
```

Comment: Problems: 1) that it's a part of higher function that I want to transform to numba, so best solution without wrapper. but maybe profiling and restructing can help wrap not important things 2) without `order='F'` I got: `Expected:
    array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],
           [0.5, 0.1, 0.4],
           [0.2, 0.7, 0.1]])
Got:
    array([[0.1, 0.5, 0.2],
           [0.3, 0.1, 0.7],
           [0.6, 0.4, 0.1]])` so I will have to make `order='F'` myself without numpy . And https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html seems no support for `order`